# Converting a string into ArrayCollection (C#, see string below)

Tags: c#, .net, string, arrays, arraycollection

how to get from such string ' name1{value1,value2};name2{value3}; ... nameN{value12, valueN} '

Array or arrays in such form: Array = {string, int};{string, int};{string, int};

like this:

```
{
 { name1 ; value1}
 { name1 ; value2}
 { name2 ; value3}
...
 { nameN ; valueN}
}
```

in C# (.net)?

Comment: Can the structure be recursive? Do you need to validate its correctness and handle possible bad input, or can you assume that it will be well formed. Can the strings contain semi-colons, braces, or escaped quotes, etc.?

Comment: no - no bad input possible. no validation needs. you can assume that it will be well formed. strings are Escaped (like browser escaped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can assume that the document will always be well-formed:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> results = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("input.txt"))
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"^\s*{\s*(.*?)\s*;\s*(\d+)\s*}\s*$");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string s = match.Groups[1].Value;
        int i = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
        results.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,int>(s,i));
    }
}

foreach (var kvp in results)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ; {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

Result:

```
name1 ; 1
name1 ; 2
name2 ; 3
nameN ; 23
```

If name1, name2, ... , nameN are unique and you don't care about the order then you may prefer to use a `Dictionary` instead of a `List`. If you really want an array instead of a list (you probably don't) then you can use `ToArray()`.

Comment: Can I swich to use dictionary just bu replacing ' List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> results = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(); ' to  ' Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, int>> results = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(); ' ?

Comment: @Ole Jak: Use `Dictionary<string, int>` and you also need to change the Add line to `results.Add(s, i);`.